# external oAuth Server for API

Tags: api, oauth

I have an API with an oAuth 2 Server implementation to verify clients. Currently the API & oAuth Server are on one server. I was wondering if I can move the oAuth Server to a different location and use it as an external service, but I am not sure if it is a stupid idea.

My plan would be:

**Client** -> *Request (with oAuth credentials)* -> **API.example.com** -> *Request (with oAuth credentials)* -> **oAuth.example.com**

**on success oAuth**

**oAuth.example.com** -> return success -> **API.example.com** (do some work) -> return result -> **Client**

I would like to do this to separate the oAuth and API because I have some technological difficulties in the past and updating the API can break the oAuth (if the underlying technology changes).

Are there any risks to this idea? Are there any resources where I could get a better idea of potential risks or problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked Phil Sturgeon via Twitter and he replied that it is a good practise to separate your oAuth Server to a different server or at least a different code base, which he certainly uses as well. He also writes this in his book "Build APIs you won't hate".

Since he has been working on many APIs & API-Driven projects I would consider this a legit source and a good answer.